# Calculating percentages within category using geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

This has been asked in various forms before, but I'm attempting it in a slightly different way and can't seem to get it exactly right. When I use this code:

```
d %>% 
  drop_na(attend) %>% 
  count(race, attend) %>% 
  group_by(race) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(race, percent, fill = race)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

I get this figure:

[image]

The 'attend' variable is just 0s and 1s, and I want to display the **percent of 1s within each race**. I think that those lines that are showing up inside the charts are actually correct, but what's going on with the rest of those columns? I can't quite figure out that last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result filter your data for `attend == 1` values after computing the percentages.

Note: The blacks lines appear because of overplotting, i.e. as you set `position = "dodge"` the bars for `attend=0` and `attend=1` are plotted on top of each other.

Using some random example data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(
  race = sample(c("Asian", "White", "Hispanic", "Black", "Other"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  attend = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

d %>% 
  drop_na(attend) %>% 
  count(race, attend) %>% 
  group_by(race) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>% 
  filter(attend == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(race, percent), percent, fill = race)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I hadn't thought of this! That works perfect. Is there a different option other than position=dodge that would achieve something similar?

Comment: Nop. If you want to show only `attend=1` than you have to filter. Another option would of course be to use the default `position="stack"` (with `fill=attend` or `group=attend`) to show a stacked bar showing both categories.

Comment: Yeah, I had a stacked bar before and was trying to figure out if this other method was possible. Thanks.